# Can I create an android app with radio frequency (without internet )

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to create a radio app in android using a radio frequency (without internet).
So, when doing some re-searches, I found all samples using streaming.
Can someone tell me some If we can create the radio frequency android app without any internet connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific API to access FM Radio. All the source codes are proprietary. But you can find some reverse-engineered code or library for specific devices on google.